# Setting environment variables to compile node on Mountain Lion with XCode4.4

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, xcode4, g++

After upgrading to Mountain Lion (10.8) and XCode 4.4, and installing the XCode Command Line utilities from the XCode Preferences pane, I was unable to compile node.js (0.8.5) from source.  Specifically, the configure script believed that I did not have a C compiler installed.

It looks to me like the environment variables required for the command line tools were lost somewhere along the way.

I tried `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` but this did not appear to clear up the problem.

I had to perform these steps to make the node build system happy:

- `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`
- `export CC='gcc --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/'`
- `export CXX='g++ --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/'`

After that I was able to compile and link.

So... why did I have to do this?  Am I missing some easy step that could have done this for me automatically?  Or am I in some bad state because I installed XCode before upgrading to Mountain Lion, and the XCode updater went off the rails?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've updated to Mountain Lion and updated XCode 4.4, you have to reinstall the command line tools inside XCode.

Go to XCode/Preferences/Downloads/Components and click install on "Command Line Tools" and once it has downloaded and installed, you should once again have gcc and g++ in your (normal) path.

Comment: When I view that preference pane, the list is empty, with a "No components are available" bubble in grey over the table view.  The "Check and Install Now" button, while active, reports that "No updates are available" when I click.  Is there some way to reset the downloaded-items list so I can do this again?

Comment: @michaelhanson Not to my knowledge, I can see both installed/up to date/non installed items there. Sounds like your upgrade indeed went a bit wrong.

Comment: Poking around in Console, I see this: Xcode[28957]:  DVTDownloadable: Failed to refresh index from <https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-88E83FA6-3505-42AD-941F-8F46A939170C.dvtdownloadableindex>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted." (Value missing for key inside <dict> at line 296) UserInfo=0x400399860 {NSDebugDescription=Value missing for key inside <dict> at line 296, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.}

Comment: @michaelhanson Sounds like Apple is having some trouble with their update server, I got a "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted" when pressing check for updates. Worked a few days ago, so may be temporary.

Comment: And, that XML file, while downloadable, is, in fact, invalid XML, on line 296.  It has a stray </string> tag.

Comment: @michaelhanson Not sure there's much to do until Apple fixes that then, sadly :-/

Comment: Logged as Apple bug #12048911

Comment: did you managed to find a fix? Would reinstalling xcode help?

Comment: @Dan The problem was a problem with Apple's update servers, if you're having the same issue again maybe they're having a bit of an overload because of recent IOS6/MacOS updates.

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do was to reinstall the command-line tools from inside Xcode.

This was temporarily impossible because a malformed download list was being served by Apple, but the problem was fixed.  The malformation was detectable by inspecting the output from Xcode in Console.

Once the tools were reinstalled, compilation worked normally.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Installing_the_Xcode_Command_Line_Tools_on_a_Mac

Please refer the above link and try to install command line from apple developer portals